# Tikz code that used to compile doesn't compile anymore after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tikz-pgf, ubuntu

I have a piece of code that compiles nicely in Ubuntu 18.04.
I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and the very same code doesn't compile anymore, while it still compiles in 18.04.
In both distribution I installed the official texlive and the same TeX-related packages.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}           

\newcommand{\cycle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{120/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
  \foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n ] \v in {#1}
    \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize,inner sep=2pt] (\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
    \draw[semithick,-stealth] (\j) to [bend right=\b] (\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \cycle{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{document}
```

The output (obtained in 18.04...) is the following:
[image]

The error in Ubuntu 20.04 is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \n 
              *0.2
l.18   \cycle{1,2,3,4,5}
                        
?
```

Comment: That `\n` variable cannot be seen outside of the `\foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1};` loop. Not sure if there is a "define globally" version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
\foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
```

I don't think that tikz ever promised to remember variables like this and I remember that there was a recent change that broke this behaviour. If you want to remember the value of `\n` then you need to use something like:

```
\foreach[count=\c] \v in {#1} {\xdef\n{\c}}%
```

Note that you need to use `\xdef` since `\foreach` loops take place inside a TeX group.

Personally, I prefer putting in a few more braces so I would write your code as:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\cycle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=3]
    \foreach[count=\c] \v in {#1} {\xdef\n{\c}}% count the number of elements
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{120/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
    \foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n ] \v in {#1} {
      \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize,inner sep=2pt] (\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
    }
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
    \draw[semithick,-stealth] (\j) to [bend right=\b] (\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \cycle{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{document}
```

In any case, this produces your desired output:

[image]